Passing environment to the yml configuration file for Azure Machine Learning component
I want to create Azure Machine Learning component with custom environment. I've created the Environment and uploaded it to my workspace.
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
from azure.ai.ml.entities import BuildContext

custom_env_name = "aml-my-custom-env"

custom_job_env = Environment(
    build=BuildContext(path="path/to/folder/with/Dockerfile"),
    name=custom_env_name,
    version='1',
    description="Custom environment",
    tags={},
)

I can see it in UI in Azure that it's created. Now I want to create component with the yml file.
YML configuration file
name: my_component
display_name: Run test code
version: 1 
type: command
inputs:
  data_path: 
    type: uri_folder
code: .
environment: 
  name: aml-my-custom-env
  version: 1
command: >-
  python test_code.py 
  --data_path ${{inputs.data_path}} 

Code
from azure.ai.ml import load_component

data_component = load_component(source=os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'configs', "my_component.yml"))

data_component = workspace_ml_client.create_or_update(data_component)

But I'm getting this error:
1) Ensure all parameters required by the Environment schema are specified.
If using the CLI, you can also check the full log in debug mode for more details by adding --debug to the end of your command
I also tried passing only the environment name as a value and the Asset ID, but still cannot run it. I also tried to run it on a different environment which I used for a different job, and I'm still getting the same errors. Do you know what could be wrong here?

Okay, I found what was an issue. The problem was I previously created this component but with a different environment. And because the environment field is not mutable when I tried to update the old one I got this kind of error (for me it's a little bit confusing but OK). However, if someone will have the same issue how to correctly link your environment inside the yml file here is the correct version:
name: my_component
display_name: Run test code
version: 1 
type: command
inputs:
  data_path: 
    type: uri_folder
code: .
environment: azureml:aml-my-custom-env@1
command: >-
  python test_code.py 
  --data_path ${{inputs.data_path}} 

